# How to display html code on homepage

Tags: php, homepage

I have some HTML code wrapped in a div tag that I'd like to place on the homepage.

Because I use a static page for a homepage, I'm guessing I should use is_front_page() and I should place the desired code in footer.php

This is what I have now in footer.php (just the snippet we need):

```
<?php>
 if (is_front_page()) 
  {
    //div html here
  }
?>
</body> </html>
```

What am I doing wrong here? Should I use echo in the php? Or should I use an OR statement in the IF (is_home OR is_front_page)

Comment: could you please elaborate whether you want that to display "html"code on all pages or just on homepage.
Also do you have header.php file in you themes folder ?

Comment: I think there is no `is_home_page` function. Where have you put your code?

Comment: That was a typo, I meant is_front_page, but they already fixed my problem. I didn't do the php syntax right, I'm a total newbie to php so I made many mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are just trying to put HTML inside PHP, just close PHP and wrap with HTML

```
<?php if ( is_front_page() ) { ?>
    <div>
        HTML Code
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

And use [is_front_page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_front_page)

Comment: It still doesn't work. When I just place my div html in the footer.php in the <body> tag it works - but on all pages.
When I put the div tag in this php you gave me, it doesn't work. Where should I place this php anyway? I tried doing it in the body, html and outside those tags but still didn't work.

Comment: Can you post your complete code so that, I can let you know. Please make sure, you try with is_home() as well. Thanks

Comment: Corrected the code. Try it now

Comment: It works now, Robert. Thanks.

Can I edit the if statement to my likings? Putting something like if (is_front_page() || is_single() ) so they display on homepage and on single posts page?

Comment: Yes you can do that, it will work. But keep PHP syntax correct otherwise it will not work.